# How to dice a large 3D image (numpy array) into smaller arrays without distorting it

Tags: python, arrays, keras, multidimensional-array

I have a large 3D image as an np.array (ax, by, cz) that needs to be diced into smaller 3D arrays (abc, x, y, z) without distorting the image. In other words, each of (x,y,z) arrays should represent a small portion of the bigger 3D image. Each of the (x,y,z) arrays are then converted to a 2D (x, y*z) array, so that I could see the data in one section.
Here are the steps:

1. Load the data stored in separate files
2. Find the shape of the array
3. Trim the array to make it dividable to abc equal pieces
4. Use the reshape function to dice the trimmed 3D array;  output shape: (abc, x, y, z)
5. Use the reshape function to flatten each dice to 2D arrays; output shape (abc, x, yz)

The problem:
The reshape function distorts the chunk of the bigger image stored diced arrays. I don’t want any distortion because it adds unnecessary complexity for algorithm training in Keras.
I have attached the function below. Any advice/suggestion is welcome!

**UPDATE:**
I revised the code to demonstrate a demo of how the image gets distorted after reshaping the array. I first generate a 3D array that the location of elements is stored as their value in the array.
I think the final image (crop_and_flattened) **should be** a crop from the top left corner of big_image.

```
big_image = np.zeros([100,100,100])
for i in range(big_image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(big_image.shape[1]):
        for k in range(big_image.shape[2]):
            big_image[i,j,k] = str(i)+str(j)+str(k)

plt.imshow(big_image[0,:,:])
dims_orig = np.shape(big_image)
# Cropped shape of cube, with axes set to multiples of 32.

dims_crop = np.array( [dims_orig[0]//32*32, dims_orig[1]//32*32, dims_orig[2]//32*32], dtype=np.int32 )
# Final shape of cube for processing.
dims_fin  = np.array( [-1, 32, 256, 1], dtype=np.int32 )
# Crop the cube.
crop_image = big_image[:dims_crop[0],:dims_crop[1],:dims_crop[2]]
plt.imshow(crop_image[0,:,:])
crop_and_flattened = np.reshape (crop_image, dims_fin, order='C')
plt.imshow(crop_and_flattened[0,:,:,0])
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a code snippet that defines some small demo data and shows that `reshape` distorts it?

Comment: @TMBailey I revised the code as suggested. Let me know if you need further clarification!

Comment: When I look at **small** data with `big_image.shape` (5, 5, 5), `crop_image.shape` (4, 4, 4) and `crop_and_flattened.shape` (8, 2, 4, 1), I can print the values in `crop_and_flattened`.  They look sensible to me, but I'm not sure what order you want them to be in.

Comment: @TMBailey, The problem happens when one of the dimensions is bigger than the original array. as reshape() goes to fill one of the dimensions, say, the dimension of
size 256 in my demo, it can't do that with a contiguous section of the original
array; at only 96 in size it's too short, resulting in an under-run. When
this happens, reshape() increments the next higher dimension in the
original array and begins copying data from the next row.
The same happens when considering the size 108 dimension, and a similar
happens with the size 32 dimension, except that that results in an
overrun.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to preserve the 2D contiguity of interest if you use `np.split` and `np.concatenate` instead of `reshape`.

In the example below I reduce the size of the "image" so it is feasible to print parts of the array and see what's going on.  Also, I leave out the cropping for the sake of simplicity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

big_image = np.zeros([4, 4, 4])
for i in range(big_image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(big_image.shape[1]):
        for k in range(big_image.shape[2]):
            big_image[i,j,k] = str(i)+str(j)+str(k)

big_image[0]
# array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
#        [10., 11., 12., 13.],
#        [20., 21., 22., 23.],
#        [30., 31., 32., 33.]])


# Add new dimension in which to stack up sub-arrays.
diced = big_image[np.newaxis, ...]

# Split array on each dimension x, y, z and stack along first dimension.
for dim in range(3):
    diced = np.concatenate(np.split(diced, 2, axis=1+dim),
                            axis=0)
diced.shape
# (8, 2, 2, 2)

diced[0,0]
# array([[ 0.,  1.],
#        [10., 11.]])

# Flatten yz.
flat = diced.reshape(diced.shape[:2] + (-1,))
flat[0, 0]
# array([ 0.,  1., 10., 11.])
```